# No resource owner with name 'check-facebook'

Tags: symfony, hwioauthbundle

I am trying to implement HWIOAuthBundle with FOSUserBundle for having both standard (login and registration) and OAuth (login and registration).

I don't know how to finalise this.

Here is my config files:

## config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    globals:
        title: %app_title%
        contact: %app_contact%

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        # path:     "%database_path%"
#config.yml
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: IService\MyFuckingBundles\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: false #change to true for production use!

hwi_oauth:
    # name of the firewall in which this bundle is active, this setting MUST be set
    firewall_name: social
    connect:
        confirmation: false
        #account_connector: hwi_oauth.user.provider.fosub_bridge
        #registration_form_handler: hwi_oauth.registration.form.handler.fosub_bridge
        #registration_form: fos_user.registration.form

    resource_owners:
        facebook:
            type:                facebook
            client_id:           11111111111111111
            client_secret:       abcdefg
            scope: "email"
            options:
                display: popup

    fosub:
        # try 30 times to check if a username is available (foo, foo1, foo2 etc)
        username_iterations: 30

        # mapping between resource owners (see below) and properties
        properties:
            facebook: facebookID
```

## security.yml

```
# app/config/security.yml
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            remember_me:
                key: %secret%
        social:
            pattern: ^/c

            oauth:
                failure_path: /c/connect
                login_path: /c/connect
                check_path: /c/connect
                provider: fos_userbundle
                resource_owners:
                    facebook: "/c/connect/check-facebook"

                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: hwi_oauth.user.provider.fosub_bridge

            anonymous: true
            logout: true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/c/connect, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

## routing.yml

```
i_service_score_it_page:
    resource: "@IServiceMyFuckingBundlesPageBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

i_service_score_it_user:
    resource: "@IServiceMyFuckingBundlesUserBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

fos_user_security:
  resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
  resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
  prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
  resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
  prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
  resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
  prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
  resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
  prefix: /profile


hwi_oauth_redirect:
  resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
  prefix:   /c/connect

hwi_oauth_login:
  resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
  prefix:   /c/connect

hwi_oauth_connect:
  resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
  prefix:   /c/connect

#HERE ADD FACEBOOK, TWITTER AND LINKEDIN SSO
hwi_facebook_login:
  pattern: /c/connect/check-facebook
```

and finally my User.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Users
 * 
 */
namespace IService\MyFuckingBundles\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="c_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="facebook_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $facebookID;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="facebook_access_token", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $facebookAcessToken;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="google_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $googleID;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="google_access_token", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $googleAccessToken;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get Facebook_id
     */
    public function getFacebookID(){
        return $this->facebook_id;
    }

    /**
     * set facebook Id
     * @return User
     */
    public function setFacebookID($facebook_id){
        $this->facebook_id = $facebook_id;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

When I am trying the authentication with the following steps:
* url -> /c/connect I have the facebook connect link
* Click on it and then accept the facebook login
* Finally returning on the website and I am having this error: No resource owner with name 'check-facebook'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you might be disappointed with the registration process.  I found it to be quite byzantine and finally gave up.  It requires two different redirect urls (one for login and one for connecting) which not all oauth servers support.  Facebook and Google do so you should be okay.  I don't think twitter support multiple callback or if it does then I could not get it to work.

In any event, I found I had to use named routes for the check login stuff (which is different than the connect stuff)

```
security.yml
...
oauth:
    resource_owners:
        facebook: facebook_login_check
        google:   google_login_check

routing.yml
    facebook_login_check:
        pattern: /login/check-facebook

    google_login_check:
        pattern: /login/check-google
```

I never tracked down why but I think the "%resource_owner%_login_check" is hard coded somewhere and used to match the callback route to a specific resource owner.

In any event, give named routes a shot and see if that get's you passed the error.  If it does then I suspect your fun will just be beginning.

============================================================

Update 1

I remember that I also had to add these named routes.  Not sure but you could try it.

```
routing.yml

github_connect:
    pattern: /connect/github

google_connect:
    pattern: /connect/google

twitter_connect:
    pattern: /connect/twitter
```

Comment: I made this change but there is still the same error.

Comment: Please update your question to show your changes.  I would suggest starting a brand new project Symfony 2 project, add the HWIOAuthBundle (no FOSUserBundle yet) then follow follow the config instructions as closely as possible.  That will isolate the cause of this error.  The OAuth bundle has a simple user object for testing.